# Como mudo a cor do iontabs?

Tags: ionic, ionic3, aba

Gastaria de mudar a cor do ion tab, eu consegui mudar a cor dos icones e do texto, mas o tab em si nao consigo modificar, eu sou bem iniciante no IONIC 3. Vou mostrar o codigo até entao.

home-entregador.html

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="2" class="teste" >
    <ion-tab [root]="entregas" tabIcon="cube" tabTitle="Entrega"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="perfil" tabIcon="person" tabTitle="perfil" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="configuracao" tabIcon="settings" tabTitle="configuracao"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

home-entregador.scss

```
page-home-entregador {
    .teste{
        background: #545454;
    }
}
```

tentei outros metodos mas não funcionaram então comecei a tentar qualquer coisa. Se alguem poder ajudar, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

As cores da guia podem ser alteradas usando variáveis Sass. Veja o aplicativo de conferência para um exemplo de exemplo: [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/tree/master/src/theme404](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/tree/master/src/theme)

Em variables.scss:

```
// Use the primary color as the background for the toolbar-md-background
$toolbar-md-background:                   color($colors, primary);

// Use the default background for the tabbar since it inherits from toolbar
$tabbar-md-background:                    #f8f8f8;

// Change the color of the tabs text
$tab-button-md-active-color:              color($colors, primary);
$tab-button-md-inactive-color:            #8c8c8c;

// Change the color of the segment button text
$toolbar-md-active-color:                 #fff;
$toolbar-md-inactive-color:               #fff;
$segment-button-md-text-color-activated:  #fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver fazendo alguns testes, aqui esta resolução:

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="2" color="verd" >
    <ion-tab [root]="entregas" tabIcon="cube" tabTitle="Entrega"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="perfil" tabIcon="person" tabTitle="perfil" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="configuracao" tabIcon="settings" tabTitle="configuracao"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

este "verd" em `color="verd"` é uma cor que eu adicionei em variable.scss

Comment: show de bola...

Answer (score 0):

Oi! Tudo tranquilo?

Você consegue adicionando classes à aba também, como por exemplo:

No HTML:

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="2" color="verd" >
    <ion-tab [root]="entregas" tabIcon="cube" tabTitle="Entrega" class="entrega"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="perfil" tabIcon="person" tabTitle="perfil" class="perfil"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="configuracao" tabIcon="settings" tabTitle="configuracao" class="config"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Então é só referenciar no css normalmente pelo nome da classe que funciona. :)

Algo como:

```
ion-tabs ion-tab.entrega { ... }
ion-tabs ion-tab.perfil{ ... }
ion-tabs ion-tab.config{ ... }
```